# Type is not assignable to mapped type

Tags: typescript

In the following example I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MapType<ReturnT>'.(2322)`. This doesn't make sense to me as the return type of the `strToTs` function is basically string | number | any, depending on a different type.

```
type RType = 'string' | 'number';

type MapType<ReturnT extends RType> =
  ReturnT extends 'string' ? string :
  ReturnT extends 'number' ? number :
  any;

function strToTs<ReturnT extends RType>(val: string, t: ReturnT): MapType<ReturnT> {
  if (t === 'string') {
    return val; // ERROR
  }
  return 15; // ERROR
}

const a = strToTs('test', 'string');
const b = strToTs('test', 'number');
```

I found some similar issues but none that really helps in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve the issue without type assertion function overloads needs to be provided.

```
function strToTs(val: string, t: 'number'): number
function strToTs(val: string, t: 'string'): string
function strToTs(val: string, t: 'string' | 'number'): string | number  {
  if (t === 'string') {
    return val; // no error
  }
  return 15; // no error
}
const a = strToTs('test', 'string');
const b = strToTs('test', 'number');
```

Why this works:

- overloads define us the function interface and the relation between arguments and return type
- implementation is working on the union `string | number` so both returns are correct in that matter

Conditional relation between argument and return type is not possible so generic approach needs type assertion:

```
function strToTs<ReturnT extends RType>(val: string, t: ReturnT): MapType<ReturnT> {
  if (t === 'string') {
    return val as MapType<ReturnT>; // assertion
  }
  return 15 as MapType<ReturnT>;  // assertion
}
```

Why conditional type does not work here. Consider plain version of the return type:

```
function strToTs<ReturnT extends RType>(val: string, t: ReturnT)
: ReturnT extends 'string' ? string : number {
  if (t === 'string') {
    return val; // error
  }
  return 15; // error
}
```

`ReturnT extends 'string' ? string : number` is resolved to `string` or `number` correctly, but the function body return is resolved to `string | number`, conditions inside the body are gathered in the union, condition inside the body of the function does not narrow the return type. That means we cannot resolved conditional type to the union never. Overloads works because implementation says return is `string | number` what is exactly correct, overloaded definition are defining how function should be used with no effect on the implementation which needs to have union of all types defined in all overloads.